# Wordpress: echo current post permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

I coding social sharing buttons in which I want to link current post in single.php template to social media share links.

The problem when I attach the permalink to share url it don`t give the full url of the post:

I tried `http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink() ?>` but only gave output of `/post/69` not `http://example.com/post/69`.

Any suggetions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Outside the post loop, you can use wordpress `get_permalink()` function for that. Inside the loop you can use `the_permalink($post->ID)` although this echos the url straight out. here is the reference from wordpress.org.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

Answer (score 1):

In WP, you can get permalink of the post with `get_permalink()` function

[Codex - get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)

You can use it like that:

```
global $post;
<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>
```

If you are in TheLoop, which probably is the case, if you are in `single.php`, then you can use `the_permalink()` - it will echo the link directly.

[Codex - the_permalink()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink)

Comment: I tried that earlier which gave the same output <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="share-facebook">

Comment: This is the code that you put in single.php in HTML section or this is what you see in HTML. Can you post the code of HTML section from your single.php?

Comment: I tested in my site in single.php and everithing was working corectly. Are you closing `a` tag `<a target="_blank" href="twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="share-facebook">Link</a>` ?

Comment: Checked. The tag is absolutely closed.

Comment: So then can you put somewhere code for your entire single.php. Check all open and close php tags. Because all tested this link just like I posted above just now and it works corectly in my case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100672/discussion-between-ihab-abdel-rahim-and-pgk).

Answer (score 0):

In your WordPress any template, page.php, single.php, serach.php or others page below code will working. `get_permalink` is WP function and `get_the_ID()` is also a WP function that will get post id, page id. Try this code.

try this function into functions.php relative permalink

```
function get_relative_permalink( $url ) {
    return str_replace( home_url(), "", $url );
}
echo get_relative_permalink(get_permalink(get_the_ID()));
```

output `/post/50/`

or

```
function get_relative_permalink( $url ) {
    $url = home_url($url);
    return esc_url($url);
}
echo get_relative_permalink($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo get_relative_permalink($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
```

or

```
global $post;
echo get_permalink($post->ID);
```

or

```
the_permalink();
```

[See this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_permalink)

[See also](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink)

Comment: All your methods should be within a loop. All gave the same current ouptut :(

Comment: try this function into functions.php relative permalink

function get_relative_permalink( $url ) {
    return str_replace( home_url(), "", $url );
}
echo get_relative_permalink(get_permalink(get_the_ID()));

Comment: function get_relative_permalink( $url ) {
     $url = home_url($url);
     return esc_url($url);
    }
    echo get_relative_permalink($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry for confusion.**

Everything is working fine except for I am using [Prepros](https://prepros.io/) live SASS compiler using custom port for preview `example.com:4000` which was causing the problem. As long as I switched to standard url `example.com`, everything is working fine.

Thanks for all on their precious contributions.